# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.springapp.mvc.Class' does not have the property 'Courses'

Tags: java, jstl, el, propertynotfoundexception

Here's my model:

```
public class Class {
    @ManyToMany(etc etc)
    @JoinTable(etc etc)
    public List<Course> Courses;
```

Here's my view:

```
<c:forEach items="${classes}" var="class">
<tr>
    <td>${class.className}</td>
    <td>
    <c:forEach items="${courses}" var="course">
        <input type="checkbox"
            <c:if test="${class.Courses.contains(course)}"> checked</c:if>>
        ${course.courseName}
    </c:forEach>
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The view only produces this 500 error:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.springapp.mvc.Class' does not have the property 'Courses'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL do not look for properties but for getters:

```
public class AnyClass {

  private String aProperty;

  private String getAGetter() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

`${anyClass.aProperty}` will fail, `${anyClass.aGetter}` will succeed.

To transform a getter name into an EL expression, the "get" (or "is") prefix is removed, and the first char is lowercased.

In your case, I guess your getter name is `getCourses`, which gives `courses`. So you have to use `${class.courses}`.

---

Be aware that you do not follow the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).